# AngularJS en Archivos TPL PrestaShop

Tags: angularjs, prestashop

Estoy intentando integrar un módulo en PrestaShop ayudándome de AngularJS para reducir el trabajo en la modificación de dicho framework para ecommerce. El detalle esta que al momento de querer acceder a las variables de mi modelo JS, al parecer existe problemas al querer imprimirlos con `{{}}` por ejemplo

```
<div ng-app="">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
```

lo que esta en `{{name}}` no funciona,sin embargo he probado esto:

```
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">    </p>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
```

y con eso descarto de que no este funcionando el Angular ya que en esta si funcionó perfectamente ¿Existe algún modo de poder incluir esa instrucción en los tpl sin afectar su funcionamiento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre corregir el problema, o mejor dicho logre encontrar una alternativa a usar de esa forma el acceso e impresion de los valores fue con lo siguiente

```
<div data-ng-bind="value"></div>
```

"data-ng-bind" este atributo me permitio hacer lo que queria.

Comment: `ng-bind` y `{{}}` son equivalentes. La diferencia es que el primero es una directiva y el segundo una expresión. Debe haber alguna otra razón por la que las expresiones no te están funcionando. Quizás el hecho que estés usando PrestaShop. De lo contrario usar una expresión es completamente natural y no debería causar problemas. Por cierto el `ng-app` de tu ejemplo está vacío. Debería ser `ng-app="miApp"` o algo parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que tu error ha estado en este parte:

```
<div ng-app="">
```

Ya que no le has indicado qué controlador o qué app tiene que lanzar.

Ejemplo utilizando scopes:

**Ejemplo:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var angularApp = angular.module('miApp');

</script>

<div ng-app="miApp">
<div ng-controller="AppController">
        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>



Controlador JS


var app = angular.module('ofertaCex', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.slider', 'angular.filter']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    $scope.name = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes escapar de smarty.
Utilza {literal}

Seria asi:

```
<h1>Hello {literal}{{name}}{/literal}</h1>
```